# NSArrayM objectatindex index 1 beyond bounds [0..0]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem in my project showing results in a tableview. I have events alloc in NSmutableArray "ActosPueblo" and the uitableview print correctly this results, but when click in row ocurred an error "NSArrayM objectatindex index 1 beyond bounds [0..0]" or just show details from different row istead of the clicked row.

My code in .m is...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *titulo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@, %@", tipoNombreDia, tipoNumeroDia, tempNombreMes];
self.title = titulo;

//loading antes de pedir los datos
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Cargando..." maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];

[self cargarActosPueblos];


}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

return [actosPueblo count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

NSDictionary *dictionary =[actosPueblo objectAtIndex:section];
NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"ActosPueblo"];

return [array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CalendarioActosViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


NSDictionary *dic = [actosPueblo objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

NSArray *array = [dic objectForKey:@"ActosPueblo"];

NSString *tipoEvento = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"TipoEventos"];
cell.labelEvento.text = tipoEvento;

NSString *tipoMunicipio = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Municipio"];
cell.labelMunicipio.text = tipoMunicipio;

NSString *tipoGanaderia = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Ganaderias"];
cell.labelGanaderia.text = tipoGanaderia;

NSString *tipoFecha = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Fecha"];
cell.labelFecha.text = tipoFecha;

NSString *tipoHora = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Hora"];
cell.labelHora.text = tipoHora;

NSString *indexP = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fila: %ld", (long)indexPath.row];
cell.index.text = indexP;

NSString *urlImagen = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ImagenEvento"];
//precarga imagen con SDWebImage
//precarga imagen con SDWebImage
if([urlImagen length] == 0){
    cell.celdaThumb.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sin-icono.png"];
}else{
    [cell.celdaThumb setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlImagen] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sin-icono.png"]];
}


actos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary* dic in array) {

    CalendarioActos *actPob = [[CalendarioActos alloc] init];

    actPob.apGanaderia= [dic objectForKey:@"Ganaderias"];
    actPob.apEvento = [dic objectForKey:@"TipoEventos"];
    actPob.apFecha = [dic objectForKey:@"Fecha"];
    actPob.apHora = [dic objectForKey:@"Hora"];
    actPob.apMunicipio = [dic objectForKey:@"Municipio"];
    actPob.apProvincia = [dic objectForKey:@"Provincia"];
    actPob.apToroImagen = [dic objectForKey:@"Imagen"];

    [actos addObject:actPob];

}

return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]){
    self.checkedIndexPath = nil;
}else{
    self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;
}

CalendarioActosViewCell *cell =(CalendarioActosViewCell*) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"actoTodiaActo" sender:cell];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"actoTodiaActo"]){
    CalendarioActosDetallesViewController *detallesController= (CalendarioActosDetallesViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableViewAP indexPathForSelectedRow];


        cal = [actos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   /* NSString *index = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", [actos count]];
    //alerta campo vacío
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Count Actos" message:index delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    // Mostrar alerta
    [alert show];*/


    detallesController.tempEvento = cal.apEvento;
    detallesController.tempFecha = cal.apFecha;
    detallesController.tempGanaderia = cal.apGanaderia;
    detallesController.tempHora = cal.apHora;
    detallesController.tempImagen = cal.apToroImagen;
    detallesController.tempMunicipio = cal.apMunicipio;
    detallesController.tempProvincia = cal.apProvincia;


    NSString *datos = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@", cal.apEvento, cal.apFecha, cal.apGanaderia, cal.apHora, cal.apMunicipio, cal.apProvincia, cal.apToroImagen];
    NSLog(@"pasamos: %@", datos);


}

}
```

"ActosPueblo" contains data from url with JSON from function "cargarActosPueblos" in viewload.

I see other questions with same problem from stackoverflow.com but no results for me.

Please check my code and accept any suggestion.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` all you really need to do is perform the segue since you will be getting the selected item in `prepareForSegue`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                               didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"actoTodiaActo" sender:self];
}
```

> "NSArrayM objectatindex index 1 beyond bounds [0..0]"

Means you're accessing elements that is greater than the size of the array.

---

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                        cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//Get the tipo at this index
NSDictionary *dic = [actosPueblo objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *array = [dic objectForKey:@"ActosPueblo"];
NSDictionary *tipo  = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Configure the cell
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CalendarioActosViewCell*cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
                                                                forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.labelEvento.text = tipo[@"TipoEventos"];
cell.labelMunicipio.text = tipo[@"Municipio"];
cell.labelGanaderia.text = tipo[@"Ganaderias"];
cell.labelFecha.text = tipo[@"Fecha"];
cell.labelHora.text = tipo[@"Hora"];
cell.index.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fila: %ld", (long)indexPath.row];
NSString *urlImagen = tipo[@"ImagenEvento"];

if([urlImagen length] == 0){
    cell.celdaThumb.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sin-icono.png"];
}else{
    [cell.celdaThumb setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlImagen] 
                         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sin-icono.png"]];
}


return cell;
}
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"actoTodiaActo" sender:self];
}
```

**prepareForSegue**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"actoTodiaActo"]){

    //Get the Selected tipo at this index
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableViewAP indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSDictionary *dic = [actosPueblo objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dic objectForKey:@"ActosPueblo"];
    NSDictionary *tipo  = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    CalendarioActosDetallesViewController *detallesController = 
       (CalendarioActosDetallesViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;      

    detallesController.tempEvento = tipo[@"TipoEventos"];
    detallesController.tempFecha = tipo[@"Fecha"];
    detallesController.tempGanaderia = tipo[@"Ganaderias"];
    detallesController.tempHora = tipo[@"Hora"];
    detallesController.tempImagen = tipo[@"ImagenEvento"];
    detallesController.tempMunicipio = tipo[@"Municipio"];
    detallesController.tempProvincia = tipo[@"Provincia"];

    //log
    NSString *datos = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@",
                    cal.apEvento, cal.apFecha, cal.apGanaderia, cal.apHora, 
                    cal.apMunicipio, cal.apProvincia, cal.apToroImagen];
    NSLog(@"pasamos: %@", datos);
}

}
```

Comment: In didSelecrRowAtIndexpath, every time I press the row I save indexpath.row of array actos inside an NSObject cal and I do an a segue action. And in PrepareForSegue pass data in NSObject cal to DetailsViewController. Do you understand it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey meda, your code works correctly!! Wow!! But now new problem... When press back button no show tableview with data, show black screen and app crash with message... 

"nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar"
"Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted"
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'"

we are getting closer to the solution! Thanks for your code. Please an solution for black screen when back button?? regards ;)

Comment: I noticed you are using as the sender when doing the segue, thats why I changed to self. You should replace your segue from viewcontroller to viewcontroller

Comment: Ooohhh that's great! work fine. Thanks for all. My app work correctly now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you are creating a new array as `actos`.  Therefore it's only ever going to have one object in it (at location 0).  When you try to access it for any row other than 0, that's your crash.

I suggest using the same data structure whenever you're referencing something using an index path instead of trying to create a second array that's not `ActosPueblo`.

Comment: Please, could you try to do what you are saying to me with my code? I don't really know how to do it. Thanks in advance!